Find functions $u(x), v(x) \in L^1(\Bbb{R})$ such that their convolution $u*v(x) \notin L^\infty(\Bbb{R})$.
This exercise (with the same wording as above) is found in my professor's lecture notes. I am having trouble finding two such functions.
From Young's inequality, we know that, for any $p,q,r \in\ [1, +\infty]$ satisfying $1+\frac1r = \frac1p + \frac1q $, we have $$ \Vert u*v \Vert _r \le \Vert u \Vert _p \Vert v \Vert _q\ . $$
Setting $r=\infty$ we have that that, for any $p,q \in [1, +\infty]$ satisfying $1=\frac1p+\frac1q $, we have $$ \Vert u*v \Vert _\infty \le \Vert u \Vert _p \Vert v \Vert _q\ . $$
This gives a way to find many functions that don't satisfy the hypothesis.
I'm currently struggling to prove whether the functions $u(x)=v(x)=\frac{1}{x(1-ln(x))^2} \chi_{(0,1)}$ do or don't satisfy the hypothesis, where $\chi_{(0,1)}$ denotes the indicator function on the interval $(0,1)$. The function $\frac{1}{x(1-ln(x))^2} \chi_{(0,1)}$ is, intuitively, an interesting candidate for both $u(x)$ and $v(x)$, because it is known that this function lies in $L^1(0,1)\setminus\bigcup_{p \in (1,+\infty]}L^p(0,1)$, and so if $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ are set equal to this function, the right-hand-side of Young's inequality above is $+\infty$ for every $p,\ q \in [1,+\infty]$ with $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$, and therefore I cannot yet exclude this function from being a candidate for $u(x)$ and $v(x)$.
Am I on the right path here? Is the statement even true?

The statement is true, that is, there exists functions $f,g\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f*g\notin L_\infty(\mathbb{R})$. Here is a simple(r) example (than the one you are working with):
Consider the function $f_p(y)=\frac{1}{y^p}\mathbb{1}_{(0,1]}(y)$ where $p<1$. For $0<x<1$
\begin{align}
f_p*f_p(x)&=\int^1_0 f_p(y)f_p(x-y)\,dy=\int^x_0 \frac{1}{(y(x-y))^p}\,dy\\
&=\operatorname{Beta}(1-p,1-p)x^{1-2p}
\end{align}
For $1/2 <p<1$,  $f*f$ is continuous in $(0,1)$, $f_p*f_p\notin L_\infty(\mathbb{R})$ since $f_p*f_p(x)\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow0+}\infty$.
